# Using CacheManager inside a nopCommerce plugin

Tags: c#, caching, nopcommerce

I have created a `nopCommerce v3.5 plugin` and want `load a text file` under a Controller Action to `_cacheManager` then reuse it in next requests.

### But `_cacheManager` always return `NULL` to me for my request `Key`.

This is some part of my codes:

```
public class AbcController : Controller   
{
    private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;

    public AbcController(ICacheManager cacheManager)
    {
        this._cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    public ActionResult Test(string title,string titleLink, string backColor,  string textColor, string timeColor)
    {
        try
        {
           // myText is always NULL here >>   :(
           var myText = _cacheManager.Get<string>("myText");

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsText))
           {
              string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/plugins/Misc.Test/App_Data/text.txt");
              myText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

              // Fill cacheManager >> 
              _cacheManager.Set("myText", myText, int.MaxValue);
            }

            // Other codes ......
        }

        // Other codes ......
     }
}
```

- Do i forget some part of codes inside other classes? like **register
  someone** or...???
- What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5):

NopCommerce has two cache managers.Both are declared at DependencyRegistrar.cs:

```
builder.RegisterType<MemoryCacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<PerRequestCacheManager>().As<ICacheManager>().Named<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_per_request").InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

The default cache is the PerRequestCacheManager and you'll get an instance just by adding it to your controller constructor. If you want to use the static cache, you need to instruct Autofac to inject it when you configure the dependencies for your controller.

DependencyRegistrar.cs,

```
builder.RegisterType<MyController>()
                .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ICacheManager>("nop_cache_static"));
```

You really should use DI instead of adding an static reference to MemoryCacheManager. This way you could change the cache provider in the future if needed.

Comment: Thank you for rewording my previous answer!

Comment: There's no need to interface with the DI in NopCommerce.  You should instead supply an IStaticCache argument in your IPlugin constructor to get an instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

NopCommerce has two cache managers. You are getting an instance that works while processing the same http request, but does not span to other requests.

You need to inject an instance of the static cache manager. You can find all the info in my reply to this other question: [Nopcommerce cache seems empty after adding a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675162/nopcommerce-cache-seems-empty-after-adding-a-list/23727377#23727377]).